# Finding correct tag element with regex or next_child_element ( Beautifulsoup)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract Votes and Gross revenue for the list of movies shown on this page

https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating

I am new to python so you help you appreciated. Notice not all movies have the Gross revenue so this is tricky for me. Also the span name='nv' element is also for other fields . Please let me know the correct approach using either regex or child/next  element.
I was hoping to find a method to first search for span having text as" Gross:" if found, capture the next child span element . If not found add a N/A entry for the particular row .

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating'
respose = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(respose.content, 'html.parser')



movie_name = []
votes = []
gross = []

movie_data = soup.findAll('div', attrs= {'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

for store in movie_data:
    name = store.h3.a.text
    movie_name.append(name)





P.S : Tried using some codes but they all throwed up some or the other errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get *Gross revenue* try to select `<span>` which contains the word `"Gross:"` and then the next sibling. If this tag doesn't exits, assign some default value (`-`) to the gross revenue:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating'
headers = {'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('.lister-item-content'):
    title = item.h3.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
    rating = item.select_one('.ratings-imdb-rating')['data-value']
    revenue = item.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Gross:") + span')
    revenue = revenue.text if revenue else '-'
    print('{:<50} {:<5} {:<10}'.format(title[:50], rating, revenue))
```

Prints:

```
1. The Shawshank Redemption (1994)                 9.3   $28.34M   
2. The Godfather (1972)                            9.2   $134.97M  
3. The Dark Knight (2008)                          9     $534.86M  
4. The Godfather Part II (1974)                    9     $57.30M   
5. Schindler's List (1993)                         9     $96.90M   
6. 12 Angry Men (1957)                             9     $4.36M    
7. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King ( 9     $377.85M  
8. Pulp Fiction (1994)                             8.9   $107.93M  
9. 777 Charlie (2022)                              8.9   -         
10. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the R 8.8   $315.54M  
11. Inception (2010)                               8.8   $292.58M  

...and so on.
```

Comment: Excellent. You made this look so simple. What if the required element is not the next next span ..for example is nit scenario <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
<p>some text</p>
<span>some text here too</p>
<span data-value="120,540,719" name="nv">$120.54M</span> 


Can we also use more filter like span must have a "$" sign ?

Comment: @PriteshDas The you can use CSS selector `.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Gross:") ~ span[name="nv"]')`. This will search for `<span>` with text `Gross:` and next `<span>` that has attribute `name="nv"`. For more CSS selectors you can visit: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/

Comment: thanks one last query on this. Can we further filter span selection based on text..like these have a $ sign as an example ?

Comment: @PriteshDas You can use bs4 API, for example `.find_next_sibling()` with custom function. In that function you will test if the next sibling contains `$` in text.